# Scale all images inside table to be the same size

Tags: tables, floats

I have the following code:

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering

\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  >{\footnotesize}{l} 
  cccccc
}

Input
       &\includegraphics[width=40mm,valign=c]{Sections/supplementary/tables_figures_code/images_for_supplementary/input_modelnet_test_e0_b1_s91_t91_RCPna_mitsuba_png_20_70_0_2}
       &\includegraphics[width=40mm,valign=c]{Sections/supplementary/tables_figures_code/images_for_supplementary/input_modelnet_test_e0_b0_s54_t54_dcp_mitsuba_png_-30_0_0_2} 
       &\includegraphics[width=40mm,valign=c]{Sections/supplementary/tables_figures_code/images_for_supplementary/input_faust_test_e0_b0_s67_t67_dcp_mitsuba_png_0_-90_0_2}
       &\includegraphics[width=40mm,valign=c]{Sections/supplementary/tables_figures_code/images_for_supplementary/input_faust_test_e0_b0_s90_t90_rpmne_mitsuba_png_-20_0_0_2}

\\ \addlinespace
PRNet
       &\includegraphics[width=40mm,valign=c]{Sections/supplementary/tables_figures_code/images_for_supplementary/output_modelnet_test_e0_b1_s91_t91_prnet_mitsuba_png_20_70_0_2}
       &\includegraphics[width=40mm,valign=c]{Sections/supplementary/tables_figures_code/images_for_supplementary/output_modelnet_test_e0_b0_s54_t54_prnet_mitsuba_png_-30_0_0_2} 
       &\includegraphics[width=40mm,valign=c]{Sections/supplementary/tables_figures_code/images_for_supplementary/output_faust_test_e0_b0_s67_t67_prnet_mitsuba_png_0_-90_0_2}
       &\includegraphics[width=40mm,valign=c]{Sections/supplementary/tables_figures_code/images_for_supplementary/output_faust_test_e0_b0_s90_t90_prnet_mitsuba_png_-20_0_0_2}

\\ \addlinespace
RPM-net
       &\includegraphics[width=40mm,valign=c]{Sections/supplementary/tables_figures_code/images_for_supplementary/output_modelnet_test_e0_b1_s91_t91_rpmne_mitsuba_png_20_70_0_2}
       &\includegraphics[width=40mm,valign=c]{Sections/supplementary/tables_figures_code/images_for_supplementary/output_modelnet_test_e0_b0_s54_t54_rpmne_mitsuba_png_-30_0_0_2} 
       &\includegraphics[width=40mm,valign=c]{Sections/supplementary/tables_figures_code/images_for_supplementary/output_faust_test_e0_b0_s67_t67_rpmne_mitsuba_png_0_-90_0_2}
       &\includegraphics[width=40mm,valign=c]{Sections/supplementary/tables_figures_code/images_for_supplementary/output_faust_test_e0_b0_s90_t90_rpmne_mitsuba_png_-20_0_0_2}

\\ \addlinespace
DWC (ours)
       &\includegraphics[width=40mm,valign=c]{Sections/supplementary/tables_figures_code/images_for_supplementary/output_modelnet_test_e0_b1_s91_t91_RCPna_mitsuba_png_20_70_0_2}
       &\includegraphics[width=40mm,valign=c]{Sections/supplementary/tables_figures_code/images_for_supplementary/output_modelnet_test_e0_b0_s54_t54_RCPna_mitsuba_png_-30_0_0_2} 
       &\includegraphics[width=40mm,valign=c]{Sections/supplementary/tables_figures_code/images_for_supplementary/output_faust_test_e0_b0_s67_t67_RCPna_mitsuba_png_0_-90_0_2}
       &\includegraphics[width=40mm,valign=c]{Sections/supplementary/tables_figures_code/images_for_supplementary/output_faust_test_e0_b0_s90_t90_RCPna_mitsuba_png_-20_0_0_2}

\end{tabular*}
\caption{More results} \label{figure:more results}

\end{figure*}
```

Producing the following output:

[image]

I tried playing with `\includegraphics[width=0.195\textwidth` to fit each image to its "box" but I believe I should use something different, as this requires manual adjustment of each image.

The problem is that the original sizes of the images differ, but I would like all to fit the exact same "boundaries", E.g, that all will take **up to** 50mm by 50mm. Setting `width=50mm,height=50mm` causes image distortion, as latex tries to make the images exactly `50X50`.

Comment: I read slightly contradictory statements: you say you want the images to have the same size, but then you stress "up to". Which one is it? BTW you can just use `width=50mm` (is your page so large?) without setting the height (which distorts the image).

Comment: You are correct, I edited the question for clarity, setting only the width doesn't fix it, as some are wider and some are taller (e.g the rightmost image)

Comment: set both width and height and add `,keepaspectratio` then the image will not be distorted and it will just scale treteating those as max values

Comment: Yes! exactly what I was looking for.